# Spring retry Rest Template Retry Template functionality

Tags: java, spring, connection-timeout, spring-retry, socket-timeout-exception

I have a spring boot application that has a rest template integrated. The rest template is designed to override the connection and read timeouts. When the application times out, I have a retry template set to retry on connection and read timeouts. I am having an issue with my retry template; I am unsure why it is executing in this manner. Any advice would be helpful. Below is the code for my rest template, retry template, and the policy it is retrying. I am getting an error stating my retryTemplate bean has an error in being created. The odd thing is my log shows doWithRetry executing. I believe there is an error with the template.execute block of the code, but cannot figure out where I made a mistake.

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
    return requestFactory;
}

 @Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(backOffPeriod);

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
    template.setRetryPolicy(new ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy());
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    template.execute(new RetryCallback<Void, RuntimeException>() {
        @Override
        public Void doWithRetry(RetryContext retryContext) {
            //System.out.println("I AM RUNNING");
            throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong");
        }
    });

    return template;
}

public class ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy extends org.springframework.retry.policy.ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {
@Value("${maxAttempts:-1}")
private Integer maxAttempts;

public ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy() {
    final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);

    this.setExceptionClassifier(new Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy>() {
        @Override
        public RetryPolicy classify(Throwable classifiable) {
            if ( classifiable instanceof SocketTimeoutException || classifiable instanceof ConnectionPoolTimeoutException || classifiable instanceof ResourceAccessException) {
                return simpleRetryPolicy;
            }
            return new NeverRetryPolicy();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: do you have `@EnableRetry`

Comment: yes i do. i have integrated on my main class

Comment: You have 3 retry methods; 2 with annotations and one explicitly using a template; which is not working? Edit the question to show your calling code.

Comment: made changes to the question. not sure why the retries are not happening.

Comment: can you give a reproducer in gitlab or github ? I like to solve this :)